# Manipulating single and multiple word strings

Tags: regex, perl, foreach

I have an array containing a number of names:

```
Fred Smith
Dave Davidson
John
Andy Wood
Robin van Persie

foreach my $name ( @arrayOfNames ) {
     my ($first, $last) = $name =~ /(.*)\s+(.).*/;
     print "$first$last";
}
```

Using the foreach loop shown above it should print the following:

```
FredS
DavidD
John
AndyW
RobinvP
```

However, it does not handle one word names (John) or more than two word names (Robin van Persie) correctly:

For one word names (John) I get errors as shown below

```
Use of uninitialized value $first in concatenation...
Use of uninitialized value $last in concatenation...
```

And for more than two word names (Robin van Persie) it prints `Robin vanP` instead of `RobinvP`

How should it be changed to cater for these one word and more than two word names?
Should one word and more than two word names be moved into a new array and then dealt with later on or can the regex be altered to cater for this?

Comment: In your example, shouldn't `Andy Wood` become `AndyW`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) instead of a regex to separate the first name from the other names:

```
my ($first, @rest) = split;
```

Then [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) within [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) to extract the initials:

```
my @initials = map { substr $_, 0, 1 } @rest;
```

Then [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) them all together:

```
join '', $first, @initials;
```

Putting it all together:

```
for (@arrayOfNames) {
    my ($first, @rest) = split;
    print join '', $first, map { substr $_, 0, 1 } @rest;
}
```

Comment: That example isn't consistent. Some are surname followed by first name initial, others are initials followed by first name.

Comment: Sorry I meant SmithF, DavidsonD, John, WoodA, vanPersieR

Comment: `join '', @rest, substr $first, 0, 1;`. If you want `John` instead of `J`, add a conditional on `@rest`

Comment: Can this also be changed around to get SFred, DDave, John, WAndy ...? I tried moving things around but can get it like that? thanks

Comment: `join '', (map { substr $_, 0, 1 } @rest), $first;`. You need the parenthesis otherwise Perl treats it as part of a list `(@rest, $first)` and passes it through `map`

Comment: I do want John instead of J. What do you mean when you say "add a conditional on @rest"? thanks

Comment: Check if `@rest` is empty and print `$first` instead of the above

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a way to do this easily with regex, but this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @names = ('Fred Smith', 'Dave Davidson', 'John', 'Andy Wood', 'Robin van Persie');

my @abbvr = map { my ($n, @n) = split;
                  $n .= substr($_, 0, 1) for @n;
                  $n } @names;

print Dumper @abbvr;
```

Comment: Could you show me an example of the reverse one below your first answer?. When I try and use substr($n, 0, 0) = substr($_, 0, 1) for reverse @n; it gives me SFredS, DDaveD, John, WAndyW and vPRobinPv. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Using a regular expression:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

chomp(my @names = <DATA>);

my @abbrs = map {s/\s+(.)\S*/$1/gr} @names;

use Data::Dump;
dd @abbrs;

__DATA__
Fred Smith
Dave Davidson
John
Andy Wood
Robin van Persie
```

Outputs:

```
("FredS", "DaveD", "John", "AndyW", "RobinvP")
```

Note, if using an older version of perl that doesn't support the `/r` switch, the following will work just fine:

```
my @abbrs = map {(my $ab = $_) =~ s/\s+(.)\S*/$1/g\; $ab} @names;
```

Also, another possible edge case would be `John Paul II`.  Perhaps that abbreviation should equal `JohnPII`?  If so, the following adjustment would take care of that `s/\s+(.[A-Z]*)\S*/$1/gr`

Comment: You could change the inner `(.)` to be `(\S)` to avoid people wondering whether the `.` can match a space. However, I believe the regular expression will do the right thing with either the `.` or the `\S`.